# C:\Program Files folder equivalent on Ubuntu

Tags: directory, installed-programs

Which folder in Ubuntu is equivalent to C:\Program Files like on windows?
Where are all programs installed?

when i type

```
apt-get install leafpad
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Where do they go??? Which folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu's file system is organised according to the [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and therefore there, generally speaking, is no equivalent to `c:\program files`.

The location of package files installed through `apt` can be viewed with
`dpkg -L`, e.g.

```
dpkg -L leafpad
```

Comment: Yes thank you!!! But i don't have reputation to vote you up :(

Comment: @lewis4u but you can accept his answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: This is just telling me the package isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

On the Linux file system, there really is no one place that everything is installed to. Libraries (like a dll) are shared system wide in /lib, binary applications are in /bin and /usr/bin, etc. The binaries to those would be in /usr/bin/

Comment: I found the solution to my problem dpkg -L sublime-text-installer  with that command i get all relevant directories where that app is. Oh i don't have enough reputation to vote you up :(